# Complex Analysis - Rouches Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, rouches-theorem

Using Rouches Theorem, Determine the number of roots of the equation $z^4-6z^3+9z^2-24z+20=0$ inside the circle $|z|=2$. My problem here is that i cannot find a single dominant term? Can i choose multiple terms for my $f(z)$? If i say chose $f(z)=-6z^3+24z$ then how many roots are there?

Comment: If you have the sum (or difference) of two polynomials and one dominates the other, you can apply the theorem as well.

Comment: Doesn't that mean i could select any combination of terms for f(z), as long as the resultant is greater than g(z)? I don't understand how i will obtain the same number of roots if i choose for example f(z)= -6(z^3) + 24z, or f(z)= (z^4) - 6z^3 + 24z?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that this answer doesn't interest you. If that's so, I will delete it.

Using the rational root theorem, it's easy to see that $1$ and $5$ are roots of $z^4-6z^3+9z^2-24z+20$. Furthermore, $z^4-6z^3+9z^2-24z+20=(z-1)(z-5)(z^2+4)$. Therefore, the roots of your polynomial are $1$, $5$, and $\pm2i$. So, there's one and only one root inside the circle $|z|=2$.

Comment: Thanks Jose. This answer does interest me but it doesn't use the application of Rouches Theorem does it? I don't recognise any of his theorem here but it will help to confirm the correct answer if i can get it some other way.

Comment: @RustyBaker : You will have near insurmountable difficulties applying the Rouché theorem if you have roots on the contour $|z|=2$, here $z=\pm 2i$.

Comment: @LutzL Indeed. I meant to write that, but I forgot it.